# Return a Generic Enum

Tags: swift, generics, enums

I'm trying to achieve something to this effect:

```
enum Foo: Int { case a, b, c, d }
enum Bar: Int { case a, b, c, d }

func generate<T: RawRepresentable>(using index: Int) -> T
{
    guard let output = T(rawValue: index) else { preconditionFailure() }
    return output
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: GenericEnums.playground:18:24: error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'T' with an argument list of type '(rawValue: Int)'
    guard let output = T(rawValue: index) else { preconditionFailure() }
                       ^

GenericEnums.playground:18:24: note: expected an argument list of type '(rawValue: Self.RawValue)'
    guard let output = T(rawValue: index) else { preconditionFailure() }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "To this effect" does not explain precisely enough what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `index` should not be `Int`, but it should be `T.RawValue`, since the `RawRepresentable` protocol doesn't specify the `RawValue`'s type to be `Int`. Secondly, if you don't want to type annotate the variables you assign the return value of `generate` to, you should apply the generic type parameter, `T` to an input argument that represents the type you want to generate.

Below is a working and tested implementation of your generic function. The `value` parameter needs to be the type of the `enum` you want to generate.

```
enum Foo: Int { case a, b, c, d }
enum Bar: Int { case a, b, c, d }

func generate<T: RawRepresentable>(value ofClass: T.Type,using index: T.RawValue) -> T {
    guard let output = T(rawValue: index) else { preconditionFailure() }
    return output
}

//the output of this version needs to be assigned to a type annotated variable, 
//otherwise the compiler cannot figure out the exact type that T represents
func generate<T: RawRepresentable>(using index: T.RawValue) -> T {
    guard let output = T(rawValue: index) else { preconditionFailure() }
    return output
}

generate(value:Foo.self, using: 1) //returns Foo.b
let a: Bar = generate(using: 0)    //returns Bar.a
```

Comment: "otherwise how would the compiler know, what type should T represent?" It could know by looking at the type of the variable to which the result of `generate` is assigned.

Comment: Thanks @matt for the input, didn't even realize that was possible. Updated my answer with another version of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Dávid Pásztor's answer is the more generic one and should be used in most cases.

However if you want to do something specifically with only `Int` based `RawRepresentable` Types, 
you can do this:

```
func generate<T: RawRepresentable>(using index: Int) -> T where T.RawValue == Int
{
    guard let output = T(rawValue: index) else { preconditionFailure() }
    return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you're way over-thinking this. If the goal is to crash when a wrong raw value is supplied, do something like this:

```
extension RawRepresentable {
    init(rawValueOrDie what:RawValue) {
        self.init(rawValue:what)!
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual usage involves passing an object which generates an index for a given enum. Each type of enum has a separate generator, so I wanted to just write the generate method once.

Comment: Well, as I said, your question does not explain what actual usage / goal _is_.